# Error al enviar datos entre componente sin relación con BehaviorSubject Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

tengo un problema al momento de pasar datos entre componentes sin relación utilizando **Servicios** y **`BehaviorSubject`**, el problema es al momento de recibir los datos el **value** del la variable **`Behavior`** llega vació , no entiendo el por que aclaro mis componentes no tienen nada que ver el uno con el otro.

Mi **servicio**:

```
@Injectable()
export class GestioOperacionesService {

    private enviaRecibe = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
    enviaRecibe$ = this.enviaRecibe.asObservable();

    // Almacenar mensaje, listo para mostrarlo a quién lo pida.
    enviar(mensaje) {
        // funcion que llamará quien quiera transmitir un mensaje.
        this.enviaRecibe.next(mensaje);
    }
    constructor() { }
}
```

Mi componente que envía los datos: (No subo todo el componente solo el método:

```
  Procesar(data) {
    const urlModulo = moduloAGestionar.validarModuloGestionar(data.IdModulo);
    this.gestionServiceOperacion.enviar('Envia mensaje desde componente'); // esta linea envia el mensaje
    this.router.navigate(['/Clientes/Juridicos']);
    console.log(data);
  }
```

Mi componente que recibe:

```
 CargaDataOperaciones() {
    this.gestionServiceOperacion.enviaRecibe$.pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(mensaje => setTimeout(() => this.dataRecibida = mensaje, 0));
  }
```

Esta es la forma en la que tengo declarada la variable que recibe:

```
public dataRecibida: string;
```

Este ultimo seria el método que recibe la información enviada desde el componente y la mostraría en la vista, pero en llega vació, he intentado sin el **TimeOut**, sin el pipe sin el **take** y nada funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es precisamente haber usado un [`BehaviorSubject`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject).

> Una variante de `Subject` que requiere un valor inicial y emite su valor actual cuando alguien se suscribe.

Como ves esta clase está diseñada para emitir siempre el último valor al recibir una nueva suscripción y por eso es que requiere un valor inicial en el constructor.

```
private enviaRecibe = new BehaviorSubject<string>('valorInicial');
```

Si tu `BehaviorSubject` nunca ha emitido un valor pues lo que emite es el valor inicial en el momento en que tu componente se suscribe y como tienes un operador `take(1)` pues sólo recibes el valor `''` y no puedes recibir ninguno más.

La solución es simplemente usar un `Subject` que no emite nada hasta que no se invoca explícitamente `next`. Solo cambia esto en tu servicio:

```
private enviaRecibe = new Subject<string>();
```

Sólo después que el otro componente envía el mensaje es que tu código se ejecuta.

Comment: Voy a realizar la prueba y te cuento , Gracias

Comment: No llega nada en la variable mejor dicho ahora ni siquiera llega jajaj no se que estoy haciendo mal

Comment: @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO Eso significa que `Procesar` se está ejecutando primero que `CargaDataOperaciones`. Un `console.log` en cada método debería ser suficiente para decirte en que orden se ejecutan.

Comment: esa es la funcionalidad , cuando ejecute el evento procesar , debo enviar los datos que recibe ese método a otro componente en el método `CargaDataOperaciones` este metodo lo estoy llamando dentro de  `ngAfterViewInit() {`

Comment: @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO Eso significa que tienes un error de diseño en tu aplicación. Las suscripciones son simplemente métodos en los que escuchas. Evidentemente si envías un mensaje y no hay nadie escuchando el mensaje se va a perder. Si ambos componentes están interactuando mediante un servicio no veo razón por lo que la escucha no pueda ser inicializada en el `ngOnInit`. Mandar el mensaje siempre debe ocurrir después que **ambos** componentes se han inicializado.

Comment: Realice una prueba, volvi a utilizar `BehaviorSubject<string>('valorInicial');`asi mismo literal , y te cuento el string `'valorinicial'`llega  pero cuando hago next  para ver el mensaje no llega nada

Comment: @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO tienes un `take(1)` que esta eliminando la suscripción en el instante que recibe el primer valor. Aunque un nuevo valor es emitido por el `BehaviorSubject` ya no queda nadie escuchando sus emisiones. Lo que debes hacer es simplemente agregar el `suscribe` de `CargaDataOperaciones` en un `ngOnInit` y emites usando un timeout o en una fase posterior en el otro componente para que te funcione como debe ser.